# Parse EOF token in CUP

Tags: jflex, cup

I'm having trouble making my CUP parser parse the EOF token. I read in the documentation that using the `%cup` flag in my Jflex code implies that there is something present like this:

```
%eofval{
  return new java_cup.runtime.Symbol(<CUPSYM>.EOF);
%eofval}
%eofclose
```

This is all good and well, but when I try the following first rule in my grammar (CUP file):

```
program                 ::=   program declaration EOF
                          | /* Empty */
                          ;
```

I get the error message that EOF is not declared by CUP.

```
Error : java_cup.runtime.Symbol "EOF" has not been declared
```

Allrighty, so I add the following to my CUP file:

```
terminal EOF;
```

No, because then CUP tells me:

```
Fatal : JavaCUP Internal Error Detected: Duplicate terminal (EOF) created
enter code here
```

However, without defining the terminal EOF, and I have a look in the `sym.java` class that Cup generates I do find:

```
  public static final int EOF = 0;
```

So I'm pretty lost on how to fix this. The documentation for both is really vague on the issue.

Edit:
The main reason I want to parse the EOF token is because I want to print out my symbol table in the end and other stuff for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so instead of explicitly parsing the EOF token to execute some code I added the following "wrapper" to my grammar, which allows me to do exactly what I wanted to do.

Instead of:

```
program                 ::=   program declaration
                          | /* Empty */
                          ;
```

I now have:

```
initial                 ::=   program   {: /* Code for EOF here */ :}
                          ;
program                 ::=   program declaration EOF
                          | /* Empty */
                          ;
```

This allows me to execute code at the end of every succesful parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
program                 ::=   program declaration EOF
                          | /* Empty */
                          ;
```

You don't need EOF in this production. It's implicit.

Comment: So do you have an idea on how I could insert a codeblock that is executed after my EOF is parsed? I would like to print out my symboltable and such for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn´t forgot a ";" in any of your grammar productions corresponding to your "file.cup".