# java_cup.runtime.Symbol "EOF" has not been declared

Tags: java, eof, jflex, cup

I have alreay read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772799/parse-eof-token-in-cup) discussion, but it didn't help me.

```
start with file;
file ::= primario SEP secondario SEP terziario EOF {:fm.scriviDebug();:};
```

Where `fm.scriviDebug()` is a my custom class that prints on stdout what CUP parsed.

I have no idea where is the problem.

#### Some infos:

---

I use JFLex to scan a file and passing symbols to CUP in the following way:

```
...
{bo} {System.out.println("[BO] ["+yytext() +"]");return symbol(sym.BO);}
{bc} {System.out.println("[BC] ["+yytext() +"]");return symbol(sym.BC);}
{sc} {System.out.println("[SC] ["+yytext() +"]");return symbol(sym.SC);}
{eq} {System.out.println("[EQ] ["+yytext() +"]");return symbol(sym.EQ);}
...
```

---

I get more than one warning of the following type:

```
Warning in file "Scanner.jflex" (line 115):
Expression matches the empty string, which may lead to non-termination.
   .*  {
```

---

This is what I get while "compiling" CUP:

```
Opening files...
Parsing specification from standard input...
Error at 63(73): java_cup.runtime.Symbol "EOF" has not been declared
Closing files...
------- CUP v0.10k Parser Generation Summary -------
1 error and 0 warnings
20 terminals, 14 non-terminals, and 18 productions declared,
producing 0 unique parse states.
0 terminals declared but not used.
0 non-terminals declared but not used.
0 productions never reduced.
0 conflicts detected (0 expected).
    No code produced.
---------------------------------------------------- (v0.10k)
```

---

Another error after compiling CUP fails:

```
 cannot find symbol
           { return new java_cup.runtime.Symbol(sym.EOF); }
```

---

Please, tell me if more info are required.

Comment: Notice the messages  **1 error and 0 warnings** and **No code produced** from CUP.  There's something wrong in your CUP grammar.  You should be seeing some other messages from CUP explaining what the problem is.

Comment: I reviewed many parts of my CUP grammar and now it works, but not sure where was the problem. I suppose some non terminal symbol to be not declared.